# ubuntu 14.04 64bit Matlab 2014b installation

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, java, matlab

i tried now for days to install matlab 2014b on ubuntu14.04. but it never worked, i am now in a situation where i dont know where to look and search for. my error messages when i want to run the installer look like these:

```
tom@tom-M50Vm:~/Downloads/MLA1408/bin/glnxa64$ ./install_unix -v
Preparing installation files ...
find: "/tmp/mathworks_21957/java/jar": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
find: "/tmp/mathworks_21957/java/jarext": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
->  DVD                 = /home/tom/Downloads/MLA1408
->  ARCH                = glnxa64
->  DISPLAY             = :0
->  TESTONLY            = 0
->  JRE_LOC             = /tmp/mathworks_21957/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
->  LD_LIBRARY_PATH     = /tmp/mathworks_21957/bin/glnxa64

Command to run:
/tmp/mathworks_21957/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m   -splash:"/home/tom/Downloads/MLA1408/java/splash.png" com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/home/tom/Downloads/MLA1408" -libdir "/tmp/mathworks_21957" 

Installing ...
Fehler: Hauptklasse com.mathworks.professionalinstaller.Launcher konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
Finished
```

please help me!

tom

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you please re-run that command with default message language settings (like so: `LC_MESSAGES=C ./install_unix -v`) and replace its output with the current one? That way non-German speakers can understand the error messages.

Comment: Is there any file named "install" instead of "insall_unix"? I so, try that as @DavidFoerster suggests: `LC_MESSAGES=C ./install -v`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have your software on a CD or iso.

1. Mount the software on say `/mnt/matlab`.
2. Copy the file installer_input.txt to a working directory, say `/tmp` . Edit it appropriately.
3. Then run the command from `/mnt/matlab`:

   ```
   sh install -inputFile /tmp/installer_input.txt -root /mnt/matlab
   ```

   and you should be good to go.